# Ubuntu immediately 'forgets' sound input device setting

Tags: sound, usb, webcam, microphone

I have two microphones attached to my computer: one built into my webcam, and one as part of a USB headset. I'd prefer to to use the USB headset mic for sound input.

When the computer boots, the sound input settings window looks like this:

[image: Sound input]

Previously I would change the input device to the USB headset, close the window, and then everything would work as I'd like. However, now this setting is never saved. If I select the USB headset, close the window and then open it again, the Webcam will once again be selected. If I try and use any application that requires a mic, the computer will use the default (the webcam mic).

I'm able to workaround the problem by unplugging the webcam and then plugging it back in again after the computer boots, as this reverses the order of the input devices (leaving the USB headset as the default). But this is somewhat inconvenient.

Does anyone know what the underlying issue could be? I am running 14.10.

Comment: If you try to mute only the Webcam microphone? (Not the top `Mute`, only the `Mute` in the `Settings for Microphone` at the right).